# I need to get the value from dropdownlist and use it for updating the table using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a Drop down List consisting of 3 values(pending,delivered,processing).When the user selects one from the list and submits, the selected value should be obtained in the controller and use it for updating the table.
so far, I have got the key value of the selected drop down menu.what should be done to get the value of the key??

Comment: value of the selected dropdown is passed on submit, could you show some code..!

Comment: Make the key and value the same so pending => pending, delivered => delivered, processing => processing

Comment: You might want to look into [static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) for an easy and bake-ready solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a form with name e.g. `Formname`

```
echo $this->Form->create('Formname');
echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
   'empty'=>false,
   'options' => array(
        'pending' => 'pending', 
        'delivered' => 'delivered', 
        'processing' => 'processing'
    )
));
```

and you can get the value in controller as  `$this->request->data['Formname']['status']`

Answer (score 0):

you can generate

```
$status= array('pending' => 'pending', 'delivered' => 'delivered', 'processing' => 'processing');

$this->Form->input('status', array(
                                      'empty'=>false,
                                      'options' => $status

                                  )
                  );
```

or if you want to do with numbers as value to post you can check with array like

```
$post_arr = array('1' => 'pending', '2' => 'delivered', '3' => 'processing')

echo $post_arr [$this->request->data('status')];
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @user1991,i am sure my answer is sure help you and it would be glad for me if you will acept my answer